# Why does a colon break novaclient's glance.find_image?

Tags: python, openstack, openstack-nova

We have images in our OpenStack named `<OS> <version>:<build no>` (e.g., `CentOS 7.2.0:160708.0`). With [the Python novaclient](https://docs.openstack.org/developer/python-novaclient/ref/v2/), I can use `client.glance.find_image` with releases before Mitaka.

```
$ cat test.py
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys
from novaclient import client
nova = client.Client("2",
                     os.environ["OS_USERNAME"],
                     os.environ["OS_PASSWORD"],
                     os.environ["OS_TENANT_ID"],
                     os.environ["OS_AUTH_URL"],
                     cacert=os.environ["OS_CACERT"])
print(nova.glance.find_image(sys.argv[1]))
```

With Liberty:

```
$ python3 test.py "CentOS 7.2.0:170210.0"
<Image: CentOS 7.2.0:170210.0>
```

With Mitaka:

```
$ python3 test.py "CentOS 7.2.0:170210.0"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(nova.glance.find_image(sys.argv[1]))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/novaclient/v2/images.py", line 53, in find_image
    "images")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/novaclient/base.py", line 254, in _list
    resp, body = self.api.client.get(url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keystoneauth1/adapter.py", line 223, in get
    return self.request(url, 'GET', **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/novaclient/client.py", line 80, in request
    raise exceptions.from_response(resp, body, url, method)
novaclient.exceptions.BadRequest: Unable to filter by unknown operator 'CentOS 7.2.0'.<br /><br />


 (HTTP 400)
```

Note that the error when an image of that name does not exist is different:

```
$ python3 test.py "CentOS 7.2.0"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(nova.glance.find_image(sys.argv[1]))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/novaclient/v2/images.py", line 58, in find_image
    raise exceptions.NotFound(404, msg)
novaclient.exceptions.NotFound: No Image matching CentOS 7.2.0. (HTTP 404)
```

It's as if `find_image` is expecting a string of the form `operator: value`, but [the documentation has only this to say about `find_image`](https://docs.openstack.org/developer/python-novaclient/ref/v2/images.html):

> `find_image`(*name_or_id*)
>   Find an image by name or id (user provided input).

How do I find an image whose name contains a colon when using Mitaka?

---

```
$ nova --version
8.0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is coming from the image service (Glance). In the newer versions of Glance, there is a change in the GET API syntax, where someone can specify an "in:" operator for filtering. You can read more about this at

https://developer.openstack.org/api-ref/image/v2/index.html?expanded=show-images-detail#show-images

For your code to work, you can enclose the image name with quotes and prefix it with "in:" string:

```
print(nova.glance.find_image('in:"' + sys.argv[1] + '"'))
```

Note that Glance is pretty strict about quotes; your image name has to be wrapped with double-quotes only -- single quotes won't work. Hence, I used the single quote for the string in the above command.

Another pretty inefficient but functional option is to use list() function in nova.images and then explicitly look for the image with name sys.argv[1]:

```
ilist = nova.images.list()
for image in ilist:
    if image.name == sys.argv[1]:
        print image
        break
```

Comment: Filtering the list might be inefficient, but it is far more flexible than `find_image`, which expects an exact image name. And the `in:"..."` way won't work with older releases, so it's not as useful. Thanks for the information!